# generate reports in MYSQL between 2 dates grouped by week

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a staff timesheet table where i have timestamp of when those records are created. I now want to generate the report so that my start date is Tuesday and end date is next Monday, which is 1 week. Now i need to generate all the records grouped by this weeks time but will be next set of tuesday to monday.

This is like normal GROUP BY WEEK(Timestamp) but the WEEK numbers are not the default ones i need to generate the reports in this custom duration. I have a query working for this which groups the record efficiently by Week 1, week 2, week 3 etc.. which is picked from default mysql calendar i guess. How can i change that to generate reports grouped by custom weeks ?

Can you tel me how the following works as how the dates are picked up ?

```
SELECT WEEK(pw.date) AS Date,DATE_FORMAT(pw.date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS post_date,
SUM(wages) AS amount,SUM(pw.hours) AS hours,SUM(pw.minutes) AS minutes
FROM pos_sessions pw
GROUP BY YEAR(pw.date), WEEK(pw.date) ORDER BY pw.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [Other Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757308/how-to-group-by-week-specifying-end-of-week-day) is what you are looking for...